# Run docker swarm mode on windows 10 using multiple hosts

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-for-windows

I'm running Windows 10 with the latest updates installed. I'm trying to set up a swarm using multiple physical hosts running docker Linux containers on windows host.
When I'm running

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.154.26.150 --listen-addr 10.154.26.150:2377
```

Where

```
10.154.26.150
```

stands for physical address of my current machine (future swarm manager)
I obviously receive

```
Error response from daemon:
manager stopped:
failed to listen on remote API address: listen tcp 10.154.26.150:2377 
bind: cannot assign requested address
```

because docker for Windows running Linux containers uses hyper-v vm and doesn't know anything about address I'm trying to specify.
So here is a question if there is any small possibility to run swarm mode in this situation so that my other hosts will be able to join new swarm over physical network.

Comment: I have the same issue and created a question in the DevOps section of StackExchange: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/join-a-linux-docker-swarm-with-a-local-windows-docker-for-test-purposes. Do you have any news on the subject? Did you solved it?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using "Docker for Windows", which runs a Moby VM in Hyper-V and simulates localhost, then it's easy for a single node Swarm setup. It's not yet designed to easily join outside machines.

If you want to have a 3-node swarm to spread out your testing, where they all have easy direct access to each other, then I recommend using docker-machine to create 3 more VM's in Hyper-V running boot2docker, like so:

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch" node1
docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch" node2
docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch" node3
```

NOTE: For this to work, 1. Be sure you're in PowerShell admin mode so docker-machine can control Hyper-V and 2. You'll need to create an "external" Hyper-V Switch and use its name in creating the VM's.

Details on the switch setup, and other options like changing CPU and memory [are in the docker-machine docs](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/).

Then you can change your docker CLI to control each one directly with `& docker-machine env nodeX | Invoke-Expression` and ssh into them with `docker-machine ssh nodeX` etc.

I use this setup and it works great!

Comment: Well thank you, but it's just a single host, and this works like a charm even for me. Buy I'm trying to create a swarm across multiple host machines so they can act like a cluster. I'm assuming it doesn't work for me because of linux kernel proxy in my hyper-v Moby VM, because when I switch to windows containers I can create a swarm using my physical ip-address and other machines (running linux containers) can join my swarm. But in this case I can't make them connect to each other using overlay network (while same-host communications in the same node works fine). Digging it now.